# How to combine namespace and path to element in Schematron?

Tags: xml, schematron

I can correctly validate this XML file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<world>
    <dog>
        <ears DIRTY='no'>
        </ears>
    </dog>
    <human>
        <ears EARRING='yes'>
        </ears>
    </human>
</world>
```

with this schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
    <pattern>
        <rule context='world/human/ears'>
            <assert test="@EARRING">ears element in human must have EARRING attribute</assert>
        </rule>
        <rule context='world/dog/ears'>
            <assert test="@DIRTY">ears element in dog must have DIRTY attribute</assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>
```

but I cannot correctly validate it when I introduce a default namespace.

For example, having this as XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<world xmlns='default-namespace'>
    <dog>
        <ears DIRTY='no'>
        </ears>
    </dog>
    <human>
        <ears EARRING='yes'>
        </ears>
    </human>
</world>
```

and this as schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
    <ns prefix="mets" uri="default-namespace"/>
    <pattern>
        <rule context='mets:world/human/ears'>
            <assert test="@COLOR">ears element in human must have COLOR attribute</assert>
        </rule>
        <rule context='mets:world/dog/ears'>
            <assert test="@DIRTY">ears element in dog must have DIRTY attribute</assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>
```

it should fail (@COLOR is missing), but it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every element needs to have the namespace prefix. Change:

```
<rule context='mets:world/human/ears'>
```

to:

```
<rule context='mets:world/mets:human/mets:ears'>
```